# How to create nested list in python with oop?

Tags: python-3.x

I try to write a shopping program in python. so i need to categorizing shopping item as default or new category that user adding like below:
 1- user can add  category and item also update them.

```
shop  = [category1[ [item name : apple , count : 2 , price:1$],[item name :orange , count :2 , price:3]],category2[[item name : spoon , count :2 , price :3],[item name :fork , count :4 , price:5]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be better off using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict) for the data:

```py
shop = {
    'category1': {
        'apple': { 'count': 2, 'price': 1 },
        'orange': { 'count': 2, 'price': 3 }
    },
    'category2': {
        'spoon': { 'count': 2, 'price': 3 },
        'fork': { 'count': 4, 'price': 5 }
    }
}
```

You can still iterate over the keys if you want, and it provides sensible nesting because you can access the named keys instead of indexes.